Initialise SavedStateHandle in shared view model
I have a parent fragment and a child fragment which have a shared viewmodel. The viewmodel uses the SavedStateHandle to retain viewmodel state even after process kill. The parent fragment uses shared viewmodel to observe some actions performed by child fragment via this viewmodel. I first define the viewmodel in parent fragment, then commit the child fragment and pass few data to it via bundle arguments, and then define the same viewmodel in child fragment having scope of parentFragment.
The issue I am facing is that the SavedStateHandle in ViewModel is initialised with Parent Fragment arguments bundle data instead of child fragment arguments bundle data. I want to have child fragment bundle data in the SavedStateHandle, instead of the parent fragment one. I am facing the same issue when there is parent activity instead of parent fragment.
Here's the reference code:
class ParentFragment: Fragment {
  private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     //Initialise view model with this fragment scope

     childFragmentManager.commit {
        add(
           R.id.container,
           ChildFragment.newInstance(
             //params
           )
        )
     }
  }
}


class ChildFragment: Fragment {
  private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     //Initialise view model with this parentfragment scope
  }
}



class SharedViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel(){


// savedStateHandle here has key value pair of ParentFragment arguments data

}

